# AJAX change a div value on click inside PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to change the content of a div based on a link being clicked on a php page. The link is created through a loop and I need to pass several parameters through the URL. The div is also created through the loop so the id of the div will be variable. I'm having trouble with the AJAX to make this happen.

Below is my php:

```
<?php
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tripDestination = $row3["tripDestination"];
        $sessionID = $row3["$sessionID"];
        $price = $row3["price"];

            echo "<a href=\"#\">" . $tripDestination . ' - ' . $price . "</a>";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<div id=\"trips\"></div>";
    }
}
 ?>
```

I need to pass two variables in the URL: sessionID and tripDestination. I was able to load static content, but it needs to be dynamic. Here's my AJAX so far

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "sqlUpload.php?sessionID=35&tripDestination=SFO", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The button's click handler needs somehow to know which of the `<a>` links it is supposed to be addressing. How does it do that?  Will there be one button per link?

Comment: Or do you really want click handlers to be attached to the links themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I might think about sending the information from a `data` attribute on the link:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tripDestination = $row3["tripDestination"];
        $sessionID       = $row3[$sessionID];
        $price           = $row3["price"];
        // Store the organized data
        $data            = array(
                               'tripDestination'=>$tripDestination,
                               'sessionID'=>$sessionID,
                               'price'=>$price
                           );
        ?>
        <!-- You can store the array into json on the data attribute -->
        <a href="#" class="data-set" data-information='<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>'><?php echo $tripDestination.' - '.$price ?></a>
        <br />
        <div class="data-response"></div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // When user clicks the <a> that has the "data-set" class
    $('.data-set').on('click',function(e){
        // I like to prevent default here, just incase
        e.preventDefault();
        // Assign current obj
        var getObj  = $(this);
        // Fetch the json from the attribute
        var getData = getObj.data('information');
        // Send
        $.ajax({
            // Just send to the page, no query string
            url: "sqlUpload.php",
            // I would send POST, personally
            type: 'GET',
            // This is the data being sent
            data: getData,
            success: function(response){
                // Presumably you want to put the response into the
                // accompanying div, then you can just do next()
                getObj.next('.data-response').html(response);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: With `json-encode()` server-side don't forget to `JSON.parse()` client-side.
[This similar approach](https://jsfiddle.net/4kzcx3bn/) is also possible, with care over property names.